# Upload with multipart/form-data - Can't retrieve files in self-hosted service

Tags: c#, web-services, http, servicestack

I'm using a ServiceStack webservice to handle image-uploads.

When hosting this service in `IIS` via `AppHostBase` everything works fine.

Now i've switched to a self-hosted service running in a console-app using `AppHostHttpListenerBase`, and all of a sudden I can't get access to the uploaded data anymore.

I am using the following property to get to the file:

```
var uploadedFiles = base.Request.Files;
```

When self-hosted, this array of `IHttpFile` is empty. When hosted in `ISS` it contains the upload.

The client is sending a request with a `Content-Type` of `multipart/form-data`, which looks like this:

```
POST http://localhost:8081/upload/aaa HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary="607a4dcf-585a-483b-b7dd-9f30d902e4a8"
Host: localhost:8081
Content-Length: 69553

--607a4dcf-585a-483b-b7dd-9f30d902e4a8
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Disposition: form-data; name=file; filename=file; filename*=utf-8''file

**** IMAGE DATA ****
--607a4dcf-585a-483b-b7dd-9f30d902e4a8--
```

I am using ServiceStack version 4.0.5 from NuGet. The host-project is running .NET 4.5.

Is this not supposed to work when self-hosted or do I have to configure something to make it work?

Comment: Peter, it should work. I have just setup a fresh project in v4, and not having any issues seeing the files. [See here](https://gist.github.com/scottmcarthur/8399716) for my working code. Can you post your config, so I can understand what you do differently?

Comment: @Scott Thanks for your help. Your answer put me on the right track. Seems like `HttpListener` is very strict about the `Content-Disposition` header. The `filename` value has to be surrounded by double quotes for it to work. When I added those I could see the file. If you add an answer I will accept it.

Comment: Glad you got it working. I have added the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tested uploading a file with ServiceStack in a fresh v4 project.

Program.cs

```
using System;
using ServiceStack;

namespace Testv4
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            var appHost = new AppHost(500);
            appHost.Init();
            appHost.Start("http://*:8082/");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    public class TestApp
    {
        [Route("/upload", "POST")]
        public class UploadFileRequest {}

        public class TestController : Service
        {
            public void Any(UploadFileRequest request)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(Request.Files.Length);
            }
        }
    }

    public class AppHost : AppHostHttpListenerPoolBase
    {
        public AppHost(int poolSize) : base("Test Service", poolSize, typeof(TestApp).Assembly)
        {
        }

        public override void Configure(Funq.Container container)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form action="/upload" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <h1>Upload File</h1>
        <input type="file" name="File1" />
        <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
    </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

`HttpListener` requires `Content-Disposition` header to be quoted around the filename

> content-disposition: form-data; name="File1"; filename="somefile.jpg"